# call a php class/method in a html fault/stop due to -> symbols

Tags: php

I'm try to call a php method from  html as show here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_classes_objects.asp
I try to do by my self, and copy and past, I try in several browser (Chrme, Edge, Firefox) but the result is still the same, it doesn't work. Someone could help me? My code:

```
    <?php
    class pippo {
      function lancia(){
            echo "Yuo are here";
            echo file_get_contents("BB.html");
      }
    }
    class Fruit {
      public $name;
      public $color;

      function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name; 
      }
      function get_name() {
        return $this->name;
      }
    }
    $ss = new pippo();
    $ss->lancia();
    ?>
```

my bb.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
     <?php
        $apple = new Fruit("Apple");
        $gi = $apple->get_name();
        echo $gi." ok";
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the browser output:

```
<pre>
Yuo are here get_name(); echo $gi." ok"; ?> 
</pre>
```

It seems the call to php metod -> stop the transmission to the server. 
Does anyone experience something like this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change to `bb.php` or config your server to send `.html` files to PHP.

Comment: Most server configs will only allow php execution in `.php` files, not `.html`, try renaming `bb.html` to `bb.php`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but the issue still remains. I try to rename bb.html to bb.php -- the result is still the same. In the end I find a solution that pretty suit my targets. I change `echo file_get_contents("BB.html")` with `include BB.php` .